# When to start submission campaign for a free ebook referencing another book?

Tags: marketing, ebook

Recently I published my book "New Testament Commentary by a Mathematician" with Lulu and started an AdWords ad campaign for this book. There were zero sales and I decided to put the ebook online for free download and to stop trying to sell it.

However my other book "End of Gospel" is now in preparation with a subsidy publisher.

There are several "agressive" mentiones of "End of Gospel" in "New Testament Commentary by a Mathematician", so I hope that readers of my free ebook will read the other book also.

My question: Right now I just have put "New Testament Commentary by a Mathematician" online. Should I submit/advertise it now or should I wait when "End of Gospel" is published before advertising my free ebook which refers to it?

Comment: Maybe Adwords is not the best medium to market an ebook. Your first step, after identifying who would be interested in your book, is finding out where and how they find the books they read. Then advertise there. Blindly advertising is throwing away money. Maybe the people wanting to read your book don't see Google Ads.

Answer (score 2):

What **@what** said above is useful.

1. You need to know your audience and where to find it.
2. You need to spread the word in social media, website, blogs...

Other possible ideas:

- What if, when you published *End of Gospel*, you offered *New Testament Commentary by a Mathematician* for free with every purchase?
- Spread the word **right now** with your *New Testament Commentary by a Mathematician* readers and put that news in places that people who like the theme of your book frequent.

Comment: Yes, try to adapt some of the contents of your book to publish as a guest blogger on a handful of key blogs where you can target your projected audience.